# Read email with IMAP and PHP - Connection Refused

Tags: php, imap

I want to read a mail's inbox using PHP IMAP.

On phpinfo() i see both *OpenSSL* and *IMAP* enabled.

When trying to connect:

```
/* connect to inbox */
$hostname = "{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/tls}INBOX";
$username = 'mail@...';
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Error: ' . imap_last_error());
```

It will always throw an error:

*Can't connect to imap.glbdns2.microsoft.com,993: Connection refused (errflg=2)*

On the outlook settings it says:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try `$hostname = "{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";`

Comment: @Nope I tried, it gives back the same error.

Comment: Does your host have a firewall?

Comment: @Max I asked and support says: no. I tried from localhost and it will grab mails correctly. Which means server has a firewall and they told me wrong. Still, from localhost, it will only allow the connection with the novalidate-cert. What should I do to make it work naturally, with plain SSL and not having to mark the "lesssecureapps" for gmail? Is it not valid with just having the PHP OpenSSL enabled?

Comment: Unless you implement OAuth2 or ask you rusers to generate App Specific Passwords, you're stuck with less secure apps.  Setting up PHP to properly validate certificates is beyond my ken.  Presumably you need to point the installation at a store of root certificates.

Comment: @Max Thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem with my email server. It was not accepting request from other third party servers which was using it. After sometimes, it came down to the increased banning rules I had set for the server. The **fail2ban** was now set to permanently ban offending IPs which tried to unsuccessfully login for more than three times. I was lucky since I managed this email server myself so I un-blacklisted the IP and it works fine. Firewall problem is the most likely cause of this. Try the following:

- check your IP if it is blacklisted by any blacklist houses (the requesting server IP);
- a site like https://mxtoolbox.com/ can help;
- if you have another server (like VPS container), try running the code from it;
- if all fails, you may have to contact the: imap-mail.outlook.com people for help.